# How to receive the ACTION_SHUTDOWN when battery runs out on Android P or upper

Tags: android, broadcast, shutdown

In recent days I had developed a test APP to record the endurance time, so if we can know the shutdown time and the endurance time can calculate. But we meet a problem is: Test APP can't be listened to the shutdown broadcast before the battery runs out.

BTW: The same method on android O and its OK. I don't know why and how to resolve this issue on android P and upper, can anyone who help to me, thanks very much!!!

**code as below:**

```html
public class ShutDownBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        System.out.println("---------Shut down-------------");
        File file = new File ("/sdcard/result.txt");
        try {
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter writer = null;

                writer = new FileWriter(file, true);

                writer.write("Shut_down [" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format((new Date()).getTime()) + "]\n");
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest as below:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dou.test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <receiver
            android:name="com.dou.test.ShutDownBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN" />-->
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```